# Integrated semantic UI in DataTables is not working properl y

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables, semantic-ui

Firstly look at the view which is given by Semantic UI after integrating Semantic UI in DataTables: **https://datatables.net/examples/styling/semanticui.html**.

When I am integrating Semantic UI in my DataTables then I am not getting the same effect in my view. [This image shows the top of table which I am getting after integrating the semantics in DataTables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJWcZ.png)
Please Help. What mistake am I doing ?

Comment: I think you forget to add the semantic css and js in your code

Answer (score 1):

First we need your code you make to help you.

Second one, you don't have style and animation on the page, so the problems comes from the import of CDN. It doesn't work if you are not connected to internet.

You have to import all this link :

```
code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.semanticui.min.js
cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.6/semantic.min.js
cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.6/semantic.min.css
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/dataTables.semanticui.min.css
```

If it doesn't work after that, show us your javascript files

Comment: Thank you SD for your response. I was doing a mistake. I forgot to add semantic ui class in table tag. I fixed it by adding that class.

Comment: No problems, for a better visibility you can edit your post to indicate what was the problem ;)